# Where to find design patterns for product management web apps?

Tags: design-patterns, web-app, information-architecture, requirements

I'm creating a IA-prototype for a product-management web app.

I don't know the field (product-management) that well and I'm looking for samples.

The requirements for this Web-app are:

- web-based
- Primarily for desktops but Ipad/touch friendly, not for smaller screens. though.
- Intuitive to navigate

The features are:

- Requirement management
- Planning
- Time
- Test
- Feature request questionnaires
- Tender (Invitation to bid on a manufacturing project)

product management and Requirement management are to the best of my knowledge very similar and wording depends on which industry this is used in.

The main industry for this Web-app is manufacturing, for example furnitures, lamps and so on

One of the userstories sounds out like this

> **Business Analyst**
>
> Process Questionnaire submissions
>
> - Search for submission for a one or more questionnaires (QST)
> - Review submissions and create issues or requirements from the user > feedback (QST)
>
> Create structure for specifications
>
> - Create specifications from scratch or look up specifications created by > the Project Manager (RM)
> - Define tables of contents (structure) for specifications (RM)
>
> Manage requirements
>
> - Add requirements to specifications (RM)
> - Search for requirements (RM)
>
> Register time
>
> Register time against personally assigned tasks in project plan (PLAN)

Links to any patterns that fit the features would be great. Links to information about project live-cycles specification standards would also be a big help.

Comment: What is "specification-management"? What is a "tender" feature? Can you describe more accurately what you're trying to make, such as business goals or the problem domain?

Comment: Specification management and Requirement management are to the best of my knowledge very similar and wording depends on which industry this is used in.

The main industry for this Web-app is manufacturing, for example furnitures, lamps and so on.

Comment: Business goals are mainly to create a application to help with the outsourcing in this industry

Tender is an invitation to bid on a manufacturing project

Comment: can you edit your question to include these details rather than posting comments? Please expand the question to be as specific as possible about what various terms mean.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the comment, added some more details, hope it helps

Comment: @Katey are you sure product management is the same thing as specification management?

Comment: @Rahul: Atil made _that_ edit himself in revision 5.  Katey just changed the title in revision 6.

Comment: @Jørn You're right, I misread. My bad.

Comment: Specification management is a part of product management and therefor they are not the same

Answer (score 1):

Look at [BaseCamp](http://basecamphq.com/), [OmniPlan](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniplan/), Microsoft Project, and their many competitors. Especially BaseCamp, which is a marvel of practical and quality UX design on the web. OP is built around gantt charts.

Some of the elements you might want to include:

- Gantt charts (some love them, some hate them)
- Messaging
- Feature database
- Time tracking
- Calendar
- Milestones
- File management
- Audit trails (full versioning of all changes)

Also consider apps like [FreshBooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/) and [BlinkSale](http://blinksale.com/) which have:

- estimates
- invoicing
- online payments

Comment: Basecamp and their simple UI is great, but I'm missing somthing like Tender, RFI and RFP modules. Do you have any ideas there?